# Getting Google Maps "Areas of interest" Polygons

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, data-capture

Is there a way to obtain the polygons corresponding to the the yellow-shaded "areas of interest" / areas of commercial activity from Google Maps?
Either through

1. a Google API
2. capturing the yellow zones in the tiles as polygons (raster to vector)
3. another data source (OpenStreetMap?) that also has "areas of interest" data
4. Something else

[image: google-maps areas of interest example]